# How can I organize the code in a long format depending on which time of measurement

Tags: r, format

I have a question about converting a dataframe from a wide format into a long format. I haven't found any solutions that fit with my dataframe. We had three measurement timeslots with the same questionnaires (e.g. PANAS and two more questionnaires). My dataframe looks like this right now:

```
| code| PANAS_1| PANAS_2| PANAS1_1| PANAS1_2| PANAS2_1| PANAS2_2|

|CAPQ |   4    |    3   |    1    |   5     |    2    |    4   |

|BANI |   2    |    3   |    4    |   4     |    3    |    2   |
```

I want to put it into a format that looks like this:

```
| code| timeslot| PANAS_1| PANAS_2 | 

|CAPQ |   1     |    4   |    3    |   
|CAPQ |   2     |    1   |    5    |  
|CAPQ |   3     |    2   |    4    | 
  
|BANI |   1     |    2   |    3    |  
|BANI |   2     |    4   |    4    |   
|BANI |   3     |    3   |    2    |
```

I tried `melt()`, but I just don't know what to do because the variable names of the questionnaires aren't the same (the name of the variables in the first timeslot are plain "PANAS_1", the ones in the second timeslot begin with a 1 "PANAS1_1" and the ones in the third timeslot begin with a 2 "PANAS2_1). On top of that I have no variable that explains from what timeslot condition the items are.

I hope you can understand my problem and help me solve this. If you need further information, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `tidyverse`. You can use `pivot_longer` to put into long format, and separate out the last number after the underscore. Then, you can add a `timeslot` variable for each `code`/number combination, assuming the times are in order. Finally, you can revert to wide format with `pivot_wider` (or leave as is for further processing/analysis).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -code, names_to = c("var", "PANAS"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(code, PANAS) %>%
  mutate(timeslot = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(code, timeslot), names_from = PANAS, names_prefix = "PANAS_", values_from = value)
```

**Output**

```
  code  timeslot PANAS_1 PANAS_2
  <chr>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 CAPQ         1       4       3
2 CAPQ         2       1       5
3 CAPQ         3       2       4
4 BANI         1       2       3
5 BANI         2       4       4
6 BANI         3       3       2
```

Alternatively, you can rename your column names and include the time inside them explicitly:

```
names(df) <- c("code", paste("PANAS", rep(1:3, each = 2), rep(1:2, times = 3), sep = "_"))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -code, names_to = c("timeslot", "PANAS"), names_pattern = "PANAS_(\\d+)_(\\d+)") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(code, timeslot), names_from = PANAS, names_prefix = "PANAS_", values_from = value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `data.table`. With `melt.data.table()` you can use groups of measure.vars. In this case you can use `patterns()` to find the the groups by their suffix.

```r
library(data.table)

df <- read.table(text = "code| PANAS_1| PANAS_2| PANAS1_1| PANAS1_2| PANAS2_1| PANAS2_2
CAPQ |   4    |    3   |    1    |   5     |    2    |    4   
BANI |   2    |    3   |    4    |   4     |    3    |    2   
", sep = "|", header = TRUE)

setDT(df)

DT.long <- melt(df,
                id.vars = "code",
                measure.vars = patterns("_1", "_2"),
                variable.name = "timeslot",
                value.name = c("PANAS_1", "PANAS_2")
                )[order(code), ]

DT.long
#>     code timeslot PANAS_1 PANAS_2
#> 1: BANI         1       2       3
#> 2: BANI         2       4       4
#> 3: BANI         3       3       2
#> 4: CAPQ         1       4       3
#> 5: CAPQ         2       1       5
#> 6: CAPQ         3       2       4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>